# Pimpl idiom without pointer indirection?

Tags: c++, performance, design-patterns, pimpl-idiom, cache-locality

I'm developing a C++ API and I want to hide private implementation details from the public interface. Currently, I'm employing the Pimpl idiom for this purpose. However, I'm also mindful of minimizing cache misses resulting from pointer indirection. The utmost priority is to keep the private API hidden, and I'm comfortable with users rebuilding their projects if there's an internal API change, for example if it changes in size.

Is there a good solution for this considering newer standards, that not only effectively hide the private implementation but also address the pointer indirection? Additionally, I'm curious about whether there's a way to guide the compiler to automatically expand the size of the public class, allowing all private class members to be allocated within it while considering memory alignment.

As an illustrative example, I'm considering an approach like the one below:

**PublicAPI.h**

```cpp
class PublicAPI {
  // Public API members
  
  class PrivateAPI;
  inline PrivateAPI *imp() const { return (PrivateAPI*)m_imp};
  private:
  char m_imp[sizeof(PrivateAPI) + padding];
}
```

**PrivateAPI.h**

```cpp
class PublicAPI::PrivateAPI {
  // Private API members
}
```

Of course I want to avoid including `PrivateAPI.h` in `PublicAPI.h`. The `sizeof(PrivateAPI) + padding` is used here for illustrative purposes.

Comment: `[sizeof(PrivateAPI)` does not compile with the incomplete class `PrivateAPI`

Comment: Yes, I know, but is there a way to get the size without including the header, for example, run a pre-compilation step that stores the sizes in a file or variables and then use those variables?

Comment: You can create a `char` array of an arbitrary size, then place `static_assert(sizeof(PrivateAPI) == sizeof(m_imp);` in the destructor in the `PublicAPI.cpp` file. This way you'll always get a compile error whenever the size you've written is wrong. You should also do the same for the alignment. Google "fast pimpl" for more info

Comment: *"I want to hide private implementation details"* ... *"a way to guide the compiler to automatically expand the size of the public class [based on the size of the private implementation]"* -- These goals are at odds with each other. If the compiler knows the size of the private implementation, then the implementation is not hidden. (Dropping "automatically" could allow these goals to get along, though.)

Comment: Hmm, yes, I was hoping there was a solution for this nowadays because it doesn't seem like a too complex feature for a compiler. However, I see that this could lead to problems with circular dependencies.

Comment: https://github.com/userver-framework/userver/blob/931eaf1f4cccf016c6c15a9c184f8244fe99cf5b/universal/include/userver/utils/fast_pimpl.hpp